# How to find basis vectors for a non homogenous plane equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that I can represent one of the variables in terms of others and find basis vectors in a homogenous system. But how do that in for example $x+y+z=5$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Can we use calculus?

The plane can be thought as if it is parametrized by $x,y$ say. That is, you can solve
$$z=5-x-y$$
then the plane enters in a scheme where the two variables $x,y$ allow you to control the position in the plane together with $z=5-x-y$.
This is a map
$$\Phi:\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)\to
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\5-x-y\end{array}\right),$$
whose derivatives are
$\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\-1\end{array}\right)$ and
$\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y}=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\-1\end{array}\right)$.

These two vectors are the same to describe in the homogeneous case $x+y+z=0$, which is natural because the plane $x+y+z=5$ is parallel to the plane $x+y+z=0$.

Please tell me if this is useful, if it is not the case I will drop out this answers.

Comment: I don't think that I should be using calculus. Though I can find those basis vectors without calculus. My question is can we say that those basis vectors span both homogenous and non homogenous plane.

Answer (score 0):

Solving first the homogenous problem $x+y+z = 0$ results in a set of vectors
$$
v_1 = (1,0,-1)\,,~~~~~~~
v_1 = (0,1,-1)\,.
$$
(See another answer to this question.) We can see that any linear combination of these vectors is "in" the plane, by noting that for
$$
v = a_1 v_1 +a_2 v_2 = (a_1, a_2, -a_1-a_2)\,,
$$
it is clear that $x+y+z = a_1+a_2 +(-a_1-a_2) = 0$.

Next, we find any point in the plane defined by $x+y+z=5$, e.g. find $p_3 = (0,0,5)$. Then, any point in this plane can be written as
$$
p = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + p_3
$$
for some $a_1$, $v_1$.  In fact, given $p$, we can find $a_1$ and $a_2$ by first translating back to the plane through the origin$-$i.e., computing $p-p_3$$-$and then expanding this vector in the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$. This is the sense in which these two vectors "span" this plane.

Finally, we can talk about this using the language of *affine* geometry.  Define $p_1=v_1+p_3$ and $p_2=v_2+p_3$, and re-write the expansion of $p$ above as
$$
p = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + p_3
=a_1 (p_1-p_3) + a_2(p_2-p_3) + p_3
=a_1 p_1 + a_2p_2 + (1-a_2-a_3)p_3\,.
$$
We say that the *affine span* of the three three non-colinear *points* $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ is the plane defined by $x+y+z=5$.  The non-colinearity is of course important, because otherwise the points $p$ would all lie along a line, but the non-colinearity is guaranteed by the linear independence of $v_1$ and $v_2$

To generalize this, we define a notion of *affine independence* of a set of points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ by saying that they are affinely independent if and only if the vectors $p_2-p_1,p_3-p_1,\dots,p_n-p_1$ are *linearly* independent. Then, we can define the affine span of the points as the set of points that are *affine* combinations of the points, i.e.,
$$
p = \lambda_1p_1 + \lambda_2p_2 + \cdots + \lambda_np_n\,,
$$
where $\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n=1$.

Going back to the original problem, then, we can see that the points $p_1 = v_1 + p_3 = (1,0,4)$, $p_2 = v_2 + p_3 = (0,1,4)$, and $p_3 = (0,0,5)$ span the plane defined by $x+y+z=5$ in the *affine* sense.